# Accessing date element with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

So, I'm making a Selenium bot that makes discord accounts.
The issue that I'm facing is that I cannot access the date (so I can't enter my date of birth ).
the website is this one: *https://discord.com/register*
I have been stuck on this for a couple of hours and I still can't figure out how to change the date of birth with Selenium.
I have tried searching the months in the source code but I wasn't able to find them , this makes me think that it's impossible to access something that doesn't exist.
So can anyone help me?

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://discord.com/register")
mail=driver.find_element_by_name("email")
mail.send_keys("some_email@something.com")
username=driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username.send_keys("some username")
password=driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys("some password")
```

This is what I have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the same action as a user would do.

**First**, use explicit waits to make your script stable.
For this import
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Note, that this especially helpful to wait till your `month` input is clickable.

**Second**,
Use `CSS` or `XPath` selectors to make your script stable. In your case it is better to use css because for class names you just put a `.` before a class.

**Third**.
Simulate pressing Enter with Selenium.
For this import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

and apply enter with `.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

Use the same strategy for date and year.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://discord.com/register")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
mail = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email")))
mail.send_keys("some_email@something.com")
username = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username")))
username.send_keys("some username")
password = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password")))
password.send_keys("some password")
month = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".css-1hwfws3")
month.click()
month_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".inputMonth-IGgn-0 input")))
month_input.send_keys("December")
month_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

P.S. There are other ways as well. What I propose should be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Month']").send_keys("December")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Day']").send_keys("5")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Year']").send_keys("2018")
```

Comment: it partially works, it sets the date and the year, but not the month

Comment: He (or she) can combine my solution with your locators also.